# How To Write Functions Test Cases In Angular?

Tags: angular, testcase, angular-test

I Want to Know about Component.Ts File Test Cases ?
Test Cases Only For Functions And Methods like Insert,Update,Delete and Get.

> Compant.ts

```
getCompanies() {
    this.$.Api.Company.getAllCompanies().subscribe();
    this.Companies = this.$.Api.Company.Companies.values;
}

companyTypes() {
    let values = [];
    for (let a in CompanyTypes) {
      values.push(a);
    }
    return values;
  }
```

Comment: Please add code for what it is you would like to test

Comment: Yes I provide code this is tree type dependency in get company i so can not test properly